# Mocks with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq, rhino-mocks

Should I keep using Mocks with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?, I mean, all the information I'm gathering about mocks is kinda old, from like 2 or 3 years ago, more specific, I'm gathering info about the next frameworks [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks) and [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

But then, I don't know if I'm looking for something old or deprecated or that it's not used nowdays... I'm making a new project and I want to used the last frameworks to implement the TDD in the best way possible, and since we recently acquired the Ultimate version of VS2010, which has a lot info and utilities about testing, I wanna do the things the way they should be done.

Oh, I almost forgot, I have to use VB, and most of the info about these frameworks are in C#, I don't know if that could be relevant...

Thanks in advice!

**EDIT**

Moq along with [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) did the job

Comment: there is no correlation between using a mocking library and the version of the IDE you prefer.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm really trying to know is that it's still a good practice to use mocks or is a new/better way to test the code, I'm asking mainly cause all the info I've found it's kinda old...

Comment: Moq is not so old, is currently mantained. Rhino is probably at a end stage, but many still use it AFAIK. If you need a mock, you will discover when you write your tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moq is my mocking framework of choice, but that's just a personal preference.  And it doesn't really matter that the samples are typically written in C#, provided you can read C#, since you can use all the same methods, but with a slightly different syntax.

You really can't go wrong with either Moq or RhinoMocks.

Answer (score 2):

Rhino and Moq will both give you what you need.  If money is not an issue I would also suggest [Typemock](http://www.typemock.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Rhino, Moq and (my favorite) FakeItEasy are nice mocking/faking frameworks.

It shouldn't matter which language you're testing in (VB or C#), but to be safe check the docs for all these frameworks.  I know FakeItEasy supports VB.NET.  You should also look into Roy Osherove's book about unit testing in .NET, highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to look at the activity on the web site where the source is hosted and try to work out whether a project is being actively maintained. If there is good developer velocity then that's usually a sign of a well-supported project. All of the mocking frameworks mentioned here are fairly good bets, my personal favourite is Moq and I like to use it with MSpec (Machine.Specifications), but of course each developer or team needs to make those choices for themselves.

If you haven't already, get the [NuGet plugin](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) for Visual Studio and use that to install all your frameworks. If you are using a CI build and don't want to check these items into your version control, there is a '[no-commit workflow](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages)' for NuGet that uses the NuGetPowerTools package.

Regarding the examples being in C#, you can use the [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) to easily translate them into VB.